# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)- ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, installation, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to install apache:
`sudo apt-get install apache2`
And i am getting this error:

```
 Setting up google-cloud-sdk (132.0.0-0) ... dpkg: error processing
 package google-cloud-sdk (--configure):  subprocess installed
 post-installation script returned error exit status 1 Errors were
 encountered while processing:  google-cloud-sdk E: Sub-process
 /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Similarly i get th following output when i run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`:

```
Setting up google-cloud-sdk (132.0.0-0) ...
dpkg: error processing package google-cloud-sdk (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-cloud-sdk
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Though installing `apache2`, the error indicates that installing `google-cloud-sdk` was at one time attempted since the post-installation script is being invoked.  As suggest by @Janos Lenart, you can see the contents of the post install script in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-cloud-sdk.postinst`.  The post-inst seems to failing.  Can you try running `gcloud components post-process` as suggest by Janos?  It may require `sudo` privileges as part of the command's instructions writes a command autocomplete table to a system directory (if installed with a system package manager).

Comment: You may also want to try the same suggested command but with debugging: `gcloud components post-process --verbosity debug`.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly crude solution and might ignore an actual problem, but you can skip the post installation script by putting

```
exit 0
```

in the 2nd line of the file

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-cloud-sdk.postinst
```

Then rerun

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: i did that, so the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-cloud-sdk.postinst` file is now:   
`#!/bin/sh
set -e
/usr/bin/gcloud components post-process >/dev/null 2>&1
exit 0
`and i still get tha same error

Comment: exit 0 in 2nd line, just after the #!/bin/sh line!

Comment: /usr/bin/gcloud components post-process is the command that fails, so you can try to run it yourself (without the redirects at the end) to see some error messages

Comment: ^^^ seconding this as a means to debug, one command at a time, what exactly is the error

Answer (score 0):

If you failed to install Java and find this error then use this following instruction:

```
~$ java -version
~$ javac
```

#### checking list

```
~$ sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
```

#### remove java (put your install version e.g. java8)

```
~$ sudo apt-get purge oracle-java9-installer
```

#### then again checking list

```
~$ sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
```

### For stopping failed download packages:

#### checking list

```
~$ sudo dpkg --list | grep -i pakage_name
```

#### remove package

```
~$ sudo apt-get purge package_name
```

#### then again checking list

```
~$ sudo dpkg --list | grep -i package_name
```